# R sum replicate function working intermittently

Tags: r, for-loop, null

I'm not sure if I've found a small bug or am doing something incorrect.  This line works fine on a command line, but in a function it works most of the time but intermittently throws an error of some kind, perhaps a NULL character.  It is buried down several layers of functions so hard to debug.

```
sum(replicate(Var1, 10^((Var2 * runif(1, 0, 1)) + Var3)))
```

I've reverted to this for loop which seems to work consistently, but I don't know why the for loop works and the sum(replicate(....)) does not.

```
out1 <- 0
for (i in 1:Var1)) {
    counts <- 10^(( Var2 * runif(1,0,1)) + Var3)
    out1 <- out1 + counts
}

out1
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks

J

Comment: You might be getting unexpected inputs to Var1 and Var2. There are a few ways to check for those. The `assertr` package makes it easy to verify that your data are what they're supposed to be inside of a function. https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/assertr/vignettes/assertr.html

Comment: Thanks for that, don't think that is the problem this time because I have set these variables earlier in the code so they are actually constants.  Problem is still that it works in for loops but not the simpler more elegant statement.